# Unrecognized Windows Sockets error: 11050: no further information

Tags: java, sockets, kotlin, kotlin-coroutines

I am scanning the local network with my Java & Kotlin desktop application. (the range is 0-255 with correct ip prefix) But it is skipping some devices at network. Probably because of the timeout. So I have tried to increase the timeout but it is throwing this exception:

```
java.net.SocketException: Unrecognized Windows Sockets error: 11050: no further information
at java.base/java.net.Inet4AddressImpl.isReachable0(Native Method)
at java.base/java.net.Inet4AddressImpl.isReachable(Inet4AddressImpl.java:70)
at java.base/java.net.InetAddress.isReachable(InetAddress.java:546)
at java.base/java.net.InetAddress.isReachable(InetAddress.java:505)
at utils.BackgroundScanner$prepareThreads$1.invoke(BackgroundScanner.kt:90)
at utils.BackgroundScanner$prepareThreads$1.invoke(BackgroundScanner.kt:13)
at kotlin.concurrent.ThreadsKt$thread$thread$1.run(Thread.kt:30)
```

The code:

```
val testIp = prefix + i
val address = InetAddress.getByName(testIp)
val reachable = try {
    address.isReachable(5000)
} catch (f: java.lang.Exception) {
    f.printStackTrace()
    false
}
```

Also this code is in a coroutine thread.

Answer (score 0):

Check your Firewall settings if you are on Windows. In my case, I had an outbound rule which was blocking the IP I was trying to reach.